# how to automate to pass answer to commad line

Tags: linux, bash, git, ubuntu, unix

Trying to automate my github authentication
whenever I run `git push` it asks me for username and authentication
[image]

I want to automate it throw script so that whenever it asks for username my script will pass it
**NOTE: even git push command is automated through script**

Here is how I automates git push using script

```
read -p "Do you want to push changes? (y/n)" push_choice 
if [ "$push_choice" == "y" ];
then
git push
```

its more than this but after code hit git push command it asks me for password and username.

So is there any way that this script will pass all the information it needed because everytime it asks for same username and pass

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the command you use to clone the repository.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+push+without+password

Comment: @Bodo i used https method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SSH with public key authentication instead of password.

See e.g.
https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/about-ssh